# What would be the function or meaning of わけですし?

Tags: grammar

> 『それにしても、随分と思い切りましたわね、士道さん』
>
> 狂三が、面白がるような口調で言ってくる。士道は一瞬口ごもってから返した。
>
> 「……仕方ねえだろ。それに、狂三だって賛成したじゃねえかよ」
>
> 『まあ、それはそれですけれど。ーー確かに、折紙さんが現れる前に<ファントム>を追い払うことができたのなら、折紙さんはそもそも攻撃する目標を失う**わけですし**』

The context is that 士道 and 狂三 are carrying out some plan to prevent 折紙 from attacking “phantom”

Hi. Is the わけですし the same as わけですから? If it is, is the speaker using this construction 「～わけだから、～する／なるのは当然だ」, as is explained in this link?

> 「～わけだ」は根拠に基づいて論理的に引き出される結論を述べます。ある事実を根拠にして、当然の成り行きとして後件が起こることを表します。ｅ「～わけだから」は、「～わけだから、～する／なるのは当然だ」という形で使われることが多く、理論的に説明や解説、理由を述べるときに使われます。「～わけだから」の主語は多くの場合話し手以外の人や事柄になります。
> ⑩あなたは皆から選ばれたわけだから、頑張るのは当然だ。

https://www.jpf.go.jp/j/project/japanese/teach/tsushin/grammar/201612.html

It seems that the speaker 狂三 is explaining why she agrees with the plan because 士道 says 狂三だって賛成したじゃねえかよ. So maybe there is something omitted after わけですし, such as 「賛成するのは当然です」.

If I am on the wrong track, please tell me how to understand the わけですし.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe "「し」 - (at the end of a phrase) notes one (of several) reasons"?

Comment: @Garbaz Hi. I know し is used to introduce reasons. But what is the function of the わけ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's [this](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/reasoning) sort of construct.